# Insert data in two different tables from single Controller in Yii

Tags: php, arrays, yii

I have two different table and i want to insert data in both of them at a time.

**ONE table is verse**

```
verse(id, topic_id, surah_id, verse_text) // id is primary key,
```

**Second table is verse_translations**

```
verse_translations(id, verse_id, language_id, translations_text) // id is primary key, language_id is foreign key references with language table, // verse_id is foreign key references with verse table.
```

**Verse Create File (_form.php)**

```
<div class="form">
    <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id'=>'verse-form', 'enableAjaxValidation'=>true)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'verse_text'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model, 'verse_text', array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'verse_text'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model, 'verse_translations'); ?>
        <p class="<?php echo "tran".$model->id ?>">

            <?php 
                $errors = array_filter($model->verseTranslations);
                if(!empty($errors)) {
                    foreach($model->verseTranslations as $vt) {
                        echo $form->textArea($model, 'translation_text', array('value'=>$vt['translation_text'], 'rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50));
                    } 
                } 
            ?>

        </p>    
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

As you may see from _form file, I have called the data from verse_translations table.

**Now my questions are:**

How I keep the value of textArea that it will go in an array in controller? And How can I insert data in verse_translation table from verse create controller.

The output of _form file is like that.

**Verse Create Controller Code.**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Verse;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Verse']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Verse'];
        if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Hope you understand it clearly.

Thanks

Comment: can you post your controller coding?

Comment: pls post the code of your action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should try this

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
    $verse_model=new Verse;
    $verse_translation_model=new Verse_translations;
    if(isset($_POST['Verse']) && isset($_POST['Verse_translations']))
    {
    $verse_model->attributes=$_POST['Verse'];
    $verse_translation_model->attributes=$_POST['Verse_translations'];
    $verse_model->save();
    $verse_translation_model->save();
    echo 'data is saved in both tables';
    }
    $this->render('create',array('verse_model'=>$verse_model,'verse_translation_model'=>$verse_translation_model));

}
```

In **views in create.php**

```
$this->renderPartial('_form',array('verse_model'=>$verse_model,'verse_translation_model'=>$verse_translation_model));
```

in **_form.php**

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array('id'=>'verse-form', 'enableAjaxValidation'=>true)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($verse_model, 'verse_text'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($verse_model, 'verse_text', array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($verse_model,'verse_text'); ?>
    </div>
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($verse_model, 'topic_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($verse_model, 'topic_id', array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($verse_model,'topic_id'); ?>
    </div>
<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($verse_model, 'surah_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($verse_model, 'surah_id', array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($verse_model,'surah_id'); ?>
    </div>

<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($verse_transaction_model, 'verse_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($verse_transaction_model, 'verse_id', array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($verse_transaction_model,'verse_id'); ?>
    </div>

<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($verse_transaction_model, 'translations_text'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($verse_transaction_model, 'translations_text', array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($verse_transaction_model,'translations_text'); ?>
    </div>

<div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($verse_transaction_model, 'language_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($verse_transaction_model, 'language_id', array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($verse_transaction_model,'language_id'); ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To store in two tables (Model), you have to create two model object for each.
for ex:

> $v_model = new Verse; // For save function
>
> $vt_model = new VerseTransctions; // For save function

Pass these model object to view file and use as below.

For verse model text boxes, you have to use:

> labelEx($v_model, 'verse_text');

For verse_tarnsction model text boxes, you have to use:

> labelEx($vt_model, 'translation_text');

**In action (save / update):**

$v_model->attributes = $_POST["Verse"];

> if($v_model->save())
>
> {   $vt_model->attributes = $_POST["VerseTransctions"];
>
> $vt_model->verse_id = $v_model->id;   $vt_model->save();
>
> }